# Python Selenium not clicking <a>

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

I am trying to get my selenium script to click a `<a>` link that is in a modal.
So this is the html;

```
<div class="modal-btns">
                    <a href="" id="confirm-btn" class="btn-primary-md">Get Now</a>
                    <a href="" id="decline-btn" class="btn-control-md">Cancel</a>
                </div>
```

Now I want to click the button `Get Now`. I tried this;

```
            button = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector('#confirm-btn')
            for e in elements:
                try:
                    e.click()
                except:
                    what = 0
            print "Clicked!"
```

I started this script without headless mode. In the console it printed out `Clicked!` while in the browser nothing has happend.

How can I make this work?

==== EDIT ====

There is a also a button that triggers the modal, that just works..
That button html is;

```
<div class="action-button">
                                                <button type="button" class="btn-fixed-width-lg btn-primary-lg PurchaseButton" data-button-type="main" data-button-action="get" data-expected-price="0" data-bc-requirement="0" data-product-id="222406" data-item-id="1744006" data-item-name="SBC Cannon 2.0" data-asset-type="TShirt" data-asset-type-display-name="T-Shirt" data-item-type="Asset" data-expected-currency="1" data-expected-seller-id="52246" data-seller-name="ViacomIsPoo" data-userasset-id="" style="">
                                                    Get
                                                </button>
                        </div>
```

It clicks that button by this code:

```
            elements = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//button[contains(@class, 'PurchaseButton')]")
            for e in elements:
                try:
                    e.click()
                except:
                    what = 0
```

So the full code will be;

```
            elements = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//button[contains(@class, 'PurchaseButton')]")
            for e in elements:
                try:
                    e.click()
                except:
                    what = 0
            time.sleep(4)
            button = browser.find_element_by_id('confirm-btn')
            for e in elements:
                try:
                    e.click()
                except:
                    what = 0
            print "Clicked!"
```

But it doesn't click the confirm button...

Comment: Maybe try a different search method? E.g. ```find_element_by_xpath```?

Comment: What are you expecting to happen. There is nothing in the href ="". Put `href="#"`

Comment: Its not my website @Duck_dragon it has to trigger javascript I guess...

Comment: I already tried that @emporerblk

Comment: Is your confirm Button is a pop up ?

Comment: switch to the frame or window before trying to find the element.

use:
https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.switch_to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
driver.execute_script("document.getElementById('confirm-btn').click()")
```

Comment: Just be aware that using JS to click an element is not a user scenario... no user can  click a button that isn't visible, off screen, etc. but JS can. If you don't care about user scenarios then it doesn't matter.

Comment: It's not about visibility, it has to be a bug based on some browsing environment conditions. It has happened to me too, with a perfectly working and simple button and I ended up using JS.